# can javascript-based charting component be integrated into Flex/AS3 web app?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, charts

I'm relatively new to flex, and I'm developing a web app that needs to plot relatively large data sets (e.g. 20,000 pts divided among 8 separate curves) in a line chart. Flex built-in chart components render too slowly.

Two part question:

1. Would javascript line chart render faster than Flex line chart?
2. If so, is it possible to use a javascript-based charting solution instead of flex component, within the Flex application? Or, is this an impractical (or crazy) idea? Anyone doing this out there? How simple or complex is it?

I'm hoping it's relatively easy to integrate a pre-developed solution like EST JS, HighCharts, etc. to simplify development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com) can handle even larger sets of data. See this sample:

http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartPerformance/LineChart

Comment: Nice! I still have no idea if it's possible to call from (integrate into) a Flex program.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m not familiar with Flash/Flex, so someone else should answer that.